# Web app posts only appear of company page when logged in

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am very quickly getting sick of facebook.  Please please can someone explain to me why the following is happening.

1. I have an app which posts to the users feed.
2. We have set up a company page and this page has the app installed
3. The app settings are: This app may post on your behalf, including status updates, photos and more.
4. The app also has the following setting: Who can see posts this app makes for you on your Facebook timeline? EVERYONE
5. The php page posts to the company page

so why does the following happen (I am going insane!)

THE POSTS ONLY APPEAR WHEN I AM LOGGED INTO THE FACEBOOK ACCOUNT. When I visit the page as a normal user the post are not visible.

Now the point of having a company page and posting stuff to the page via the app is so that visitors can see it.

The app is installed. You can post updates to the page and the app permissions says that posts made by this app can be seen by everyone. Am i just be stupid or is the facebook API just a pile of crap???

Comment: App still in Sandbox mode? Privacy setting of the post? Any restrictions in place for your page (alcohol, age)? And do you really want an honest answer to your last question? :-)

Comment: I'd bet on sandbox mode or a restriction on the app which means it can't be seen by logged-out users

Comment: SandBox mode was disabled, age Anyone 13+, doesnt contain alcohol (i will soon contain a lot of it).  Privacy settings of post was specified in the app as user default.  When editing the app settings once logged into the client account the setting was EVERYONE

Comment: Also in manage permissions: Default visibility of posts by others: allowed on page

Comment: The page is at http://www.facebook.com/pages/ and is not connected to a full account. Do you think this could be causing the issue.  Maybe need to sign up as full facebook user and then add the company page?